# Не работает задержка в C#

Tags: c#

```
    private void buttonconfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (login.Text == "")
        {
            text_error.Visible = true;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            text_error.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (password.Text == "") {
            text_error.Visible = true;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            text_error.Visible = false;
        }
```

login и password это текстовые блоки и если человек оставляет эти поля пустыми или хотя бы одно у него должно показывать на экране текст(label) и через секунду убирать его, а у меня вообще ничего не показывает и все, хотя задержка есть, по кнопке видно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
private async void buttonconfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (login.Text == "")
    {
        text_error.Visible = true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        text_error.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (password.Text == "") {
        text_error.Visible = true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        text_error.Visible = false;
    }

// ...
```

Лучше не использовать `Thread.Sleep` в UI приложениях (WinForms, WPF, Avalonia, ...), т.к. этот метод полность блокирует поток и приложение вообще не обновляется, т.е. в вашем случае оно просто "виснет" на одну секунду.

Вместо этого можно использовать асинхронный обработчик и `Task.Delay`. Оно преостанавливает выполнение кода на одну секунду, но не блокирует поток, т.е. ваше приложение имеет возможноть перерисовывать окно и весь контент.

Comment: спасибо все работает, но есть вопрос, зачем писать async в функции?

Comment: Чтобы можно было внутри метода вызвать асинхронную функцию Task.Delay(1000); с помощью await, да бы не блокировать основной поток. Можете прочитать по async/await из документации Microsoft , очень полезно, и часто используется не только в C#, но и других ЯП. Если документации читать нудно, то можно ознакомиться в статье на ХАБР : https://habr.com/ru/articles/470830/ @GrafixWay

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @GrafixWay и на будущее, не кто не проверяет строки == вот так. Вызывайте string. IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: `== ""` то же самое, что `.Length == 0`, только работает медленнее. Ну или IsNullOrEmpty используйте. @GrafixWay